# How to modify the .htaccess to force ssl on login and admin pages

Tags: htaccess, ssl, https

I have the following code to force ssl on the login and admin pages via the .htaccess on a the domain example.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-(admin|loginurl) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I'm also using [iThemes Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) 'Hide-backend' to change the wp-login to 'loginurl' due to a plugin conflict i can't use iThemes Security ssl features which forces ssl via the wp-config

The problem is with the above code ssl is not applied to the login or wp-admin pages. These pages are still served as http//

How can I modify the .htaccess to force ssl on the login and admin pages?

Comment: RewriteRule ^ **http**://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: Hi can you please expand on your comment. Are you making a suggestion, asking a questions or providing an answer? Thanks

Comment: You are sending the visitors to `http`, not to `https`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);` options provided by WP. 
You just have to add the line in `wp-config.php`.
Here is the link to [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL), in case that you need more examples.

Comment: Please read my question before answering I stated this can't be done via the wp-config due to a conflict. Thanks

Comment: sorry about that. you can try like this  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/wp-admin/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>`